# Does an "aligned memory accesses" in CUDA need to address an "even multiple" of the cache granularity?

Tags: c, cuda, memory-alignment

I am reading the book, *Professional CUDA C Programming*. On page 159, it says:

> Aligned memory accesses occur when the first address of a device
> memory transaction is an even multiple of the cache granularity being
> used to service the transaction (either 32 bytes for L2 cache or 128
> bytes for L1 cache).

I am wondering why aligned memory accesses in CUDA need even multiples of the cache granularity rather than just multiples of the cache granularity.

So, I checked the *cuda-c-programming-guide* from NVDIA. It says:

> Global memory resides in device memory and device memory is accessed
> via 32-, 64-, or 128-byte memory transactions. These memory
> transactions must be naturally aligned: Only the 32-, 64-, or 128-byte
> segments of device memory that are aligned to their size (i.e., whose
> first address is a multiple of their size) can be read or written by
> memory transactions.

It seems that even multiples of the cache granularity is unnecessary for aligned memory access, isn't it?

Comment: If I see correctly, the book was not updated since 2014 which is quite old in terms of how fast things can change in hardware/CUDA. You can find the same numbers in Nvidia slides from [2010](https://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/sc_2010/CUDA_Tutorial/SC10_Fundamental_Optimizations.pdf)/[2011](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/bandwidthlimitedkernels_webinar.pdf).

Comment: As L1 cache is physically the same as shared memory (since Volta and also for some even older architectures), I would guess that one still gets 128B per "L1 transaction" (32 banks * 4B), but greater than 32B alignment should not really matter anymore as long as 128 consecutive bytes are accessed. So my hypothesis is that 128B alignment was important for some older architecture with physically separate L1 and shared memory. But this is just a guess.

Comment: @paleonix: The programming guide contradicts your hypothesis. as NVIDIA indicated otherwise? Or - have you tested this empirically on recent GPUs? Also note, that global memory access on Pascal, Volta/Turing, Ampere/Lovelace and Hopper behaves the same as on Maxwell (according to the CUDA Programming guide).

Comment: @einpoklum I think my confusion comes from the cache granularity not being specified anywhere in newer materials. From the programming guide it sounds like these alignments have nothing to do with caches (i.e. even when explicitly avoiding L1 I would have thought that 128B alignment for 128B transactions is needed for coalescing).

Answer (score 2):

The quoted sentence from the book seems to be incorrect in two senses:

1. A memory access has an *alignment of N* if it is an access to an address that is a multiple of N. That's irrespective of CUDA. What seems to be discussed here is memory access *coalescence*.
2. As you suggest, and AFAIK, coalescence requires "multiples of" the cache granularity, not "even multiples of".

Comment: I think "even multiple" might just be a horrible choice of word for trying to say an "integer multiple".

Comment: @paleonix: I guess that's possible, since these multiples are also even addresses, but we'll never know... this also occurred to me but it doesn't really help the answer to speculate about it so I left it out.